# Responsive alignment with a bootstrap input-group on the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get three items of equal width (a datepicker input-group, a dropdown and a button) to stick together in the center of a form until it becomes too small and then I want them to stack, centered within the screen.

I am using bootstrap for my navbar so I gave it a shot with columns and left-text/right-text etc. but the input-group seems immune to these class styles:

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: #ddd;">
    <form  method="GET" target="_blank">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 text-right" 
                 style="  background-color: #000;
                         align: 0 auto;">
                <div class="input-group " style="width: 216px; margin: 14px 8px 14px 8px;">
                    <input class="form-control date-picker" 
                           type="text" placeholder="Pick a Date" 
                           style="height: 40px; ">
                    </input>
                    <label for="Start-Date" class="input-group-addon btn date-picker"
                               style="min-width: 16px; height: 40px; "> 
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center" style="background-color: blue">
                <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle " 
                        data-toggle="dropdown" 
                        style="height: 40px; margin: 14px 8px 14px 8px; ">
                    <option value="0">Places</option>
                    <option>Select Date First</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-left" style="background-color: red">
                <button class=" btn btn-default "     value="Claim"
                        style="height: 40px;  padding-right: 12px; 
                                margin: 14px 8px 14px 8px; ">
                            Claim
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

(also here: http://jsfiddle.net/qfv3s0nb/)

How do I make the div stay on the same line?

Comment: I played with it on jsfiddle quite a bit and may be close. This update shows the changes:  [link]http://jsfiddle.net/qfv3s0nb/6/    It still needs the center item to stay near the two side items on wide screens, though. Any idea how to cope with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited the jsfiddle and add a width and `float:left` to each column so that the div won't go down.
here : http://jsfiddle.net/qfv3s0nb/2/

Comment: The problem is not so much the div as (1) the input-group won't right-justify (right-align) and (2) the items don't really stay together, they just exist in regions that stick together. On my screen the div never wrapped but if I adjust the window width smaller I can see what you fixed. Anyway, thanks for taking a look and tweaking but I still need to solve the main problems.